# al crear un new activity aparece error unresolve reference: android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, activity

al crear nueva activity con el asistente crea las respectivas clases y layout, pero en la clase me muestra error  unresolve reference:activity_hacienda

he prodado con distintos nombres y siempre sale el mismo error, no se que pueda ser.

```
class HaciendaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hacienda)
}
```

}

Y el codigo del layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HaciendaActivity">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UauOk.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UauOk.png)

Comment: el archivo activity_hacienda.xml de tu layou debe localizarse dentro de res/layout/ , revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Me salia el mismo error solo reinicie el Android studio "cerre el android y volvi abrir"

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el layout `activity_hacienda.xml` que cargas dentro de la funciòn `onCreate()` no existe:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hacienda)
}
```

Debes asegurar que el layout exista dentro de `res/layout/`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sucede que si estaba creado el activity_hacienda.xml, ahora cada vez que creo un activity nuevo me toca salir del programa y reiniciar y ya no me genera error, es algo extraño que me esta sucediendo aun no se como se soluciona.